# How are these two sites built to be 'responsive'?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am looking into responsive web design and have come across many methods of doing so, however I am struggling to distinguish the best method of doing so.

I -really- like the how these two sites work:

1. http://paulrobertlloyd.com/
2. http://colly.com/

However I cannot seem to figure out how the are dynamically changing their layouts. Is there a technique I am missing that is not listed below?

---

So far I have come across the following methods:

#### 1: Javascript

Example - [adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/)

Detects the screen resolution dynamically and selects the appropriate stylesheet.

---

#### 2: CSS3 Media queries

Using a technique like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) {

}
```

---

#### 3: Backend

Example - [Prepending PHP files](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2005/07/make-your-site-mobile-friendly)

Only really works for a single mobile version of a site, mirroring the original domain and changing the headers.

Comment: What about these sites? They don't seem to do anything spectacular. They wrap their content when there's little space, but with a good design this happens automatically. What specific results do you want, and how do you fail achieving them?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Look more carefully; that's not ordinary wrapping.

Comment: I see, you're right. paulrobertlloyd.com/ seems to use some Javascript trickery to determine the right sizes. You can see this when you shrink the browser until you only see the dog, and then resize it to reveil the right menu. The headers will grow and shrink until they have the right size.

Comment: No; it's not Javascript; it's pure CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those websites use media queries, as you can see in the bottoms of their respective CSS files.

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I totally missed that. I was checking in Firebug and it didn't show there was a minified CSS file!

Answer (score 2):

This is generally referred to as elastic CSS.

There is a framework for it here:  http://elasticss.com/  I should say though that I have never used it personally, so there might be something better.